# Getting value of property of object inside an array inside another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, strapi

I'm developing a blog using Strapi and React and the articles in the blog have multiple categories, I get a GraphQL query from Strapi like this

```js
(blogpostObject){
  
  "categories": [
    {
      "name": "Category 1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Category 2"
    },
  ],
  
}
```

I want to access the "name" value of each category and display them separated by commas each of them with an `<a>` tag with a link to another page.

so far I only came up with this solution

```js
queryData.map(article => (
article.categories.map(category => category.name).toString().replace(/,/g, `, `)
```

this will render: "Category 1, Category 2", but I don't know how to add the `<a>` tag to each of them from here.

EDIT: I'm using Gatsby to build this project, so I'm using React Link component to handle internal links.

This is a sample GraphQL response

```js
{
  "data": {
    "allStrapiArticle": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "title": "This is my second article",
          "slug": "this-is-my-second-article",
          "content": " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
          "id": "Article_2",
          "author": {
            "name": "Average Joe"
          },
          "categories": [
            {
              "name": "Category 1"
            }
          ],
          "created_at": "Wednesday, June 24th 2020"
        }
```

Comment: Would you post a sample of response from your graphql API?  Do you use React Router to hop between pages, or your hyperlinks should point to totally different location (if so, what's the URL for each link)?

Comment: Pay attention that both of provided answers are focused on cooking up HTML markup of hyperlinks which is not the way it is **properly** done in React.

Comment: I've added the GraphQL example to the post. I'm using Gatsby and its Link component for routing. The links will point to a page with all the articles in that category. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React from "react";

// this data would come from graphql instead
const data = {
  allStrapiArticle: {
    nodes: [
      {
        title: "This is my second article",
        slug: "this-is-my-second-article",
        content: " Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
        id: "Article_2",
        author: {
          name: "Average Joe"
        },
        categories: [
          {
            name: "Category 1"
          },
          {
            name: "Category 2"
          },
          {
            name: "Category 3"
          }
        ],
        created_at: "Wednesday, June 24th 2020"
      }
    ]
  }
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {data.allStrapiArticle.nodes.map(node => {
        return node.categories.map((category, index) => {
          return (
            <>
              <a href="/">{category.name}</a>
              {index < node.categories.length - 1 && ", "}
            </>
          );
        });
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Edit adoring-forest-3yfnj]

Comment: It worked! but for some reason I had to delete the "return" before node.categories.map() , thank you!

Comment: Also how can I separate in commas if there is more than one category?

Comment: Ok, I got the commas by enclosing everything in a fragment and adding a span with a comma inside.

Comment: Yes, that's how I would do it. I added the same with some logic so there's no trailing comma.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried

```
article.categories.map(category => <a href='#'>{category.name}</a>)
```

Comment: This will render [object Object], I'm using React so this is all jsx. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

```
queryData.map(article => (
article.categories.map(category => "<a href='#'>" + category.name + "</a>").toString().replace(/,/g, `, `
```

Comment: This renders the <a> tag as plain text. Thanks for your help